# pass parameter in jsp fails

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to pass a parameter in JavaScript function so I do this:

```
<af:textBox name="date" id="date" type="date"
                    value="<%=startDate%>" 
                    title="" onKeyUp="fieldChanged()"
                    
                    onChange="load('cod','<%=startDate%>'))
                />
```

The method javascript is this:

```
function load(idComponente,value_pass) {
    console.log("Value "+value_pass);
}
```

The problem is the `console.log` is never called when `onChange` is called.
In my console there aren't any erorrs.

Comment: "In my console there are some erors" would you mind including them?

Comment: @f1sh there aren't. I wrong write

Comment: So is the function called `load` or `ricaricaDescrizione908`?

Comment: it prints me in the field this :"<%=startDate%>" not the date that I put

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yeah it's load